# How do I move my My Documents, My Pictures, and My Videos to a different hard disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, my-documents

My 1 TB system disk (C:) is getting really full, and this is due to lots of pics and videos in my User folders.  All this is being stored on C:, but I have just installed a new 2 TB hard drive, and I would like to have Windows move all this stuff to the new drive (K:).  I know I can't just highlight, cut and paste, but how is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to do in Windows 7 and 8: Right-click the folder, e.g. *My Documents*, click on *Properties*, and in the *Location* tab, set the new location. You can put a link in the new location to the files in the C:...\My Documents folder, or move the files to the new drive. See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/redirect-folder-new-location#1TC=windows-7 (also works on Windows 8).

Comment: If you move them with the Location tab, make sure you move them to a new folder with any name on the new drive (one folder for each) and not to the root of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using Windows Easy Transfer :

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

Comment: This appears to be for transferring to a new computer, not within the existing computer.

Answer (score 0):

When I posted my comment above I had forgotten that I actually made a video tutorial long time ago that explains how to move the folders to another partition. Unfortunately I could not update my comment because of the 5 minute limit. But here is this video: https://vimeo.com/8722519